# go-sql-driver: get invalid connection when wait_timeout is 8h as default

Tags: mysql, go

## One Sentence

Got MySQL `invalid connection` issue when `MaxOpenConns` are abundant and `wait_timeout` is 8h.

## Detailed

I've a script intending to read all records from table A, make some transformation, and write the resulted records to table B. And the code works this way:

- One goroutine scans table A, putting the records into a channel;
- Other four goroutine (number configurable) concurrently consume from above channel, accumulating 50 rows (batch size configurable) to insert into table B, then accumulating another 50 rows, and so on so forth.
- Scanner goroutine holds one `*sql.DB`, and inserter goroutines share another `*sql.DB`
- go-sql-driver: either Version 1.4.1 (2018-11-14) or Version 1.5 (2020-01-07)

(problem encountered with 1.4.1, and reproducible demo, see below, uses 1.5)

- Go version: go1.13.15 darwin/amd64

The `invalid connection` issue is **almost steadily reproducible**.

In a specific running case, table A has **67227** records, channel size is set to 100000, table A scanner (1 goroutine) reads 1000 a time, table B inserter(4 goroutines) write **50** a time. It ends up with **67127** records in table B (2*50 lost), and 2 lines of error output in console:

```
[mysql] 2020/12/11 21:54:18 packets.go:36: read tcp x.x.x.x:64062->x.x.x.x:3306: read: operation timed out
[mysql] 2020/12/11 21:54:21 packets.go:36: read tcp x.x.x.x:64070->x.x.x.x:3306: read: operation timed out
```

(The number of error lines varies when I reproduce, it's usually 1, 2 or 3. **`N` error lines coincide with `N*50` records insertion failure** into table B.)

And from my log file, it prints `invalid connection`:

```
2020/12/11 21:54:18 main.go:135: [goroutine 56] BatchExecute: BatchInsertPlace(): SqlDb.ExecContext(): invalid connection
Stats={MaxOpenConnections:0 OpenConnections:4 InUse:3 Idle:1 WaitCount:0 WaitDuration:0s MaxIdleClosed:14 MaxLifetimeClosed:0}
2020/12/11 21:54:21 main.go:135: [goroutine 55] BatchExecute: BatchInsertPlace(): SqlDb.ExecContext(): invalid connection
Stats={MaxOpenConnections:0 OpenConnections:4 InUse:3 Idle:1 WaitCount:0 WaitDuration:0s MaxIdleClosed:14 MaxLifetimeClosed:0}
```

## Trials and observations

1. By printing each success/ fail write operation with goroutine id in log, it appears that the error always happen when any 1 of all 4 inserting goroutines has an over ~45 seconds interval between 2 consecutive writes. I think it's just taking this long to accumulate 50 records before inserting them to table B.
2. In contrast, when I happened to make a change so that the 4 inserting goroutines write some averagely, (i.e. no one has a much longer writing interval than others), the error is not seen. Repeated 3 times.
3. Looks one error only affects one batch write operation, and the following batches work well. So why not retry with the errored batch? I suppose one retry and it will get through. Still, I don't mind keep retrying until success:

```
var retryExecTillSucc = func(goroutineId int, records []*MyDto) {
   err := inserter.BatchInsert(records)
   for { // retry until success. This is a workaround for 'invalid connection' issue
      if err == nil { break }
      logger.Printf("[goroutine %v] BatchExecute: %v \nStats=%+v\n", goroutineId, err, inserter.RdsClient.SqlDb.Stats())
      err = inserter.retryBatchInsert(records)
   }
   logger.Printf("[goroutine %v] BatchExecute: Success \nStats=%+v\n", goroutineId, inserter.RdsClient.SqlDb.Stats())
}
```

Surprisingly, with this change, retries of the errored batch keep getting error and never succeed...

## Summary

It looks obvious that one (idle) connection was broken when the error occur, but my question is:

- MySQL `wait_timeout` is set 8h, so why is the connection timed out so quickly?
- Since MaxOpenConns is not set, it shouldn't be a limitation, especially considering the merely 4 `OpenConnections` in log.
- What else to check as potential root cause?

(Too long, but just hope to put it clearly and get some advice~)

---

### Update

[Minimal, reproducible example](https://github.com/JuneYuan/reprod-invalid-conn), including:

- Code
- One sample log file
- MySQL error log

Comment: 1. How does an 8h timeout make sense? 2. Regardless of your timeout, you should never assume that all connections are valid. There are countless reasons unrelated to a timeout, that a connection could close or be dropped.

Comment: @Flimzy timeout is suggested by the output: `[mysql] 2020/12/11 21:54:18 packets.go:36: read tcp x.x.x.x:64062->x.x.x.x:3306: read: operation timed out
`. Also puzzled because I haven't encountered such case in our production service, but in this script, it happens so regularly. If all connections are not always valid, exceptions should be very rare right?

Comment: Your error indicates a read timeout. That comes from the client, not the server. `wait_timeout` is how long the _server_ waits to close an unused connection. Even if that takes effect during a query (highly doubtful), it would produce something more like a "connection closed" error.

Comment: After RTFMing a bit, I see that the default `wait_timeout` is 8h, so that's not as crazy a value as I thought. But it's also completely unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Your "workaround" is actually fundamentally the correct thing to do.  All DB operations should be assumed to be falible, and thus your application _must_ be capable of handling a failure. A retry is a good way to do that in many situations.  You can also make it a bit more robust by doing a ping first, to ensure that the connection you grabbed from the pool is still valid, but that's probably not related to this specific problem.

Comment: @Flimzy Got your idea about `wait_timeout` unrelated, and retry good to do. Questions still on my mind: 1. Why got a read timeout when I call `*sql.DB.Exec()` to insert? 2. Timeout in client side. What can be wrong, and what can be done to avoid the timeout? 3. Ping first and then exec insert, this was an earlier version of my workaround. It behaved that ping succeeded but insert somehow errored.

Comment: For client timeouts, see [the docs](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#connection-pool-and-timeouts).

Comment: How long is your query taking?

Comment: Didn't track exact elapse, and <1s according to log timestamp.

Comment: I don't know then. There's not enough code in your question to debug, really. A [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful.

Comment: passing a context? -- No. HTTP request? -- No. Code and example, good point, lemme update in a bit~

Comment: Hi @Flimzy, just updated my question to add a [reproducible example](https://github.com/JuneYuan/reprod-invalid-conn).

Comment: Can you share the mysql logs that relates to this client side error ?

Comment: have you considered upgrading your go installation ?

Comment: can you share the my.cnf ? So we can dockerize the mysql instance, IE `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -e MYSQL_DATABASE=practice -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:????`

Comment: even though we can reproduce, if this happens to be related to the runtime, I am unsure it is going be fixed. I cant find the release lifecycle management spec, but i would doubt 1.13 will be updated in the next patch deliveries.

Comment: to manage your go versions, you can use https://github.com/moovweb/gvm

Comment: you mention in your repo that the error occurs only when you connect on a remote instance. Cant it be related to a broken connectivity ?

Comment: Hi @mh-cbon, 1. updated repo to: i. Add mysql error log; ii. Support writing as many records as specified.  2. Upgraded to go 1.15, not yet reproduced. Interestingly, switching back to 1.13 and I haven't see that error so far. Feels volatile this time lol. 3. By `broken connectivity` you mean my network shortly down? then I think unlikely, because network issue should be a lot more random, but I did see some pattern in triggering this issue~ 4. `my.cnf`, trying to get more of 2 and share my.cnf in a bit. (Many thx for the useful advice )

Comment: I strngly suggest to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/communication-errors.html

Comment: I also recommend to code more cleanly your scripts. It is better to respect the protocol implementation by calling db.Close when it is appropriate. It can help prevent such bugs. On this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175299/do-we-need-to-close-db-connection-before-closing-application-in-go

Comment: I would also consider investigating if many application are using the same user. If they are all not respecting the protocol, it might be a source of errors. As you can see it is not an easy bug to fix because it can have many reasons, some are very low level.

Comment: I suspect the variable Aborted_clients is per user, so maybe having a spceific user for that app will make the problem go away.

Comment: this should give you good hints about hw to handle ctrl+c signal. https://harsimran-kaur.medium.com/gracefully-shutdown-go-api-server-connected-to-database-17fc1267a313 Otherwise, please consider making a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you use Context? I suppose the read timeout is caused by Context Timeout, or `readTimeout` parameter.

MySQL doesn't provide safe and efficient canceling mechanism. When context is cancelled or reached `readTimeout`, `DB.ExecContext` returns without terminating using connection. It cause "invalid connection" next time the connection is used.

If you want to limit execution time of long query, you can use `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` hint instead of context.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time for reference.